# R - using mutate function from dplyr creates the wrong col name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using mutate function to add a new column in the data.
I used 2 variations but both created the column with the wrong name "Domestic_boxoffice" instead of "total_boxoffice ".

See the implementation below:

Option 1:

```r
starwars <- mutate(starwars, total_boxoffice = Domestic_boxoffice + Worldwide_boxoffice, .after=Worldwide_boxoffice)
```

Option 2:

```r
starwars %>% mutate(total_boxoffice = Domestic_boxoffice + Worldwide_boxoffice)
```

[image]

Any idea why this could happen?
In the screenshot below you can see that the first print displays the data structure and the second print after the addition of the column.

Full code:

```r
homeDir <- getwd()

csvPath <- paste(homeDir, "/starwars.csv", sep = "")

starwars <- read.csv(csvPath)

starwars <- starwars %>% mutate(total_boxoffice = Domestic_boxoffice + Worldwide_boxoffice, .after=Worldwide_boxoffice)

starwars
```

dput(starwars):

```r
structure(list(Release_date = c("Dec 20, 2019", "May 25, 2018", 
"Dec 15, 2017", "Dec 16, 2016", "Dec 18, 2015", "Aug 15, 2008", 
"May 19, 2005", "May 16, 2002", "May 19, 1999", "May 25, 1983", 
"May 21, 1980", "May 25, 1977"), Movie = c("Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker", 
"Solo: A Star Wars Story", "Star Wars Ep. VIII: The Last Jedi", 
"Rogue One: A Star Wars Story", "Star Wars Ep. VII: The Force Awakens", 
"Star Wars: The Clone Wars", "Star Wars Ep. III: Revenge of the Sith", 
"Star Wars Ep. II: Attack of the Clones", "Star Wars Ep. I: The Phantom Menace", 
"Star Wars Ep. VI: Return of the Jedi", "Star Wars Ep. V: The Empire Strikes Again", 
"Star Wars Ep. IV: A New Hope"), Production_budget = structure(c(275, 
275, 200, 200, 306, 8.5, 115, 115, 115, 32.5, 23, 11), dim = c(12L, 
1L), dimnames = list(NULL, "Production_budget")), Opening_weekend = structure(c(177.383864, 
84.420489, 220.009584, 155.081681, 247.966675, 14.611273, 108.435841, 
80.027814, 64.81097, 23.019618, 4.910483, 1.554475), dim = c(12L, 
1L), dimnames = list(NULL, "Opening_weekend")), Domestic_boxoffice = structure(c(515.202542, 
213.767512, 620.181382, 532.177324, 936.662225, 35.161554, 380.270577, 
310.67674, 474.544677, 309.205079, 291.73896, 460.998007), dim = c(12L, 
1L), dimnames = list(NULL, "Domestic_boxoffice")), Worldwide_boxoffice = structure(c(1072.848487, 
393.151347, 1331.635141, 1055.135598, 2064.615817, 68.695443, 
848.998877, 656.695615, 1027.044677, 475.106177, 549.001242, 
775.398007), dim = c(12L, 1L), dimnames = list(NULL, "Worldwide_boxoffice")), 
    total_boxoffice = structure(c(1588.051029, 606.918859, 1951.816523, 
    1587.312922, 3001.278042, 103.856997, 1229.269454, 967.372355, 
    1501.589354, 784.311256, 840.740202, 1236.396014), dim = c(12L, 
    1L), dimnames = list(NULL, "Domestic_boxoffice")), US_avg_ticket_price_in_USD = c(9.16, 
    9.11, 8.97, 8.65, 8.43, 7.18, 6.41, 5.81, 5.08, 3.15, 2.69, 
    2.23)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is it possible to dput(df)

Comment: Please show the `dput` of a small example as I can't reproduce your code with `head(mtcars) %>% mutate(new = carb + gear, .after = am)`.  FYI, if you are assigning the `starwars <-` and then reusing the same data, it may have some problems

Comment: @akrun edited the question. It can also be found in the screenshot I attached.

Comment: Your `dput` is a bit confusing because there's already a `total_boxoffice` column in it after the `Worldwide_boxoffice` column. So whatever dataset you ran `dput()` on already has your desired result--seems like your code works fine.

Comment: Your data frame is non-standard, as Production_budget thru total_boxoffice are matrices and not vectors. Run `starwars %>%  %>% glimpse()` to see this. You could use `starwars %>% mutate(across(Production_budget:total_boxoffice, as.numeric))` to convert them so they'll work with `mutate`, or better to fix your pipeline upstream of this.

Comment: (Also note the potential typos in the code you shared, you are sometimes using `starwars` all lower case and sometimes using `starWars` with a capital W. R is case sensitive, so be careful with that. If you're defining both `starwars` and `starWars` and mixing them up, that could be your problem.)

Comment: @GregorThomas the column does appear in the output of `dput` command. But it is under another title. Any idea How can  I fix that? This is exactly the bug I was asking about

Comment: This is a pretty good question now, but it would be better if you showed results in a text form instead of as a screenshot. Just posting `names()` of the results would illustrate the problem sufficiently, I think ...

Comment: Added a code example here https://posit.cloud/content/5139812. If anyone can take a look. There is a weird behavior. I have know idea why is that.

Comment: Also , I should get 3 items tagged as Sequel_trilogy but getting only 1 after filtering them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it looks like your problem is that some of your columns are matrices. @JonSpring suggests `as.numeric()`, but `drop()` might be more precise. I also suggest that you check the upstream path: it's not clear to me how the code in your question (`read.csv()`) could lead to output with this form; maybe there were other steps you didn't tell us about?

```r
(starwars 
   |> mutate(across(everything(), drop),
             total_boxoffice = Domestic_boxoffice + Worldwide_boxoffice, 
                 .after=Worldwide_boxoffice)
)
```

Comment: Oooh nice! I was starting an answer using `mutate(across(where(is.matrix), as.numeric))` but glad to learn `drop` -- more broadly useful for one-level arrays.

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.